manhwa - FL dies saving the ML and then they both reincarnate into a story
I read this manwha a few months back and i can’t remember the name.
Basically, in her previous life, the FL was a ‘Guide’ that helped her husband who went beserk. This act essentially killed her and before and after she died and got reincarnated, she thought that the ML didn’t truly like her. In the second life, the ML finds her again (i think) and shows his love to her..
I don’t know if that’s the exact plot or what happens, but at least the previous life summary is something I remember.

In the title of the question, you say the FL and ML both reincarnate into a story after the FL dies... so did their first life and second life take place in two different worlds? If so, was the first world like the real world?

This is How To Reject My Obsessive Ex-Husband.

When Yu Seohyeon sacrificed her life to save her first love, Ciel de Leopart, she never expected to wake up as Irene de Closhe in a world straight out of a book. Amidst this bizarre twist, she reunites with Ciel, who has now become a supporting male lead destined to betray the crown prince. As her unique guide abilities resurface, Seohyeon is haunted by Ciel's intense, madness-filled gaze, a stark contrast to the man she once knew. Tangled in a web of past love and new identities, Seohyeon must navigate a treacherous path where past and present collide.

The term Guide is explicitly used; the protagonist is a guide while the ML is an esper.

Espers have uncontrollable powers but guides can help bring it under control. The story opens with the ML's powers going berserk, killing both of them. The FL reincarnates in a book world and rediscovers her husband at a palace banquet. She has a different appearance and name, but he does not, so she recognizes him immediately but he only gets a vague sense of familiarity.
As the title suggests, he is obsessively in love with her and seeks her out after discovering that she also reincarnated.
